# What is the exact definition of a Metacircular Interpreter?

Tags: c, lisp, scheme, interpreter, self-interpreter

Is it legal to call a C compiler written in C or a PHP interpreter written in PHP metacircular? Is this definition valid only for languages of a specific type, like Lisp? In short, what are the conditions that an interpreter should satisfy for being called Metacircular?

Comment: JFYI, this is one of the issues that are discussed in the PLAI textbook (see www.plai.org).  Reading that will probably work out better than reading wikipedia.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A metacircular interpreter is an interpreter written in a (possibly more basic) implementation of the same language. This is usually done to experiment with adding new features to a language, or creating a different dialect.

The reason this process is associated with Lisp is because of the highly lucid paper ["The Art of the Interpreter"](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html), which shows several metacircular interpreters based on Scheme. (The paper is the kernel for the book SICP, and its fourth chapter works through others that create e.g. a lazily-evaluated Scheme.)

This is also *vastly* easier to do in a "homoiconic" language (a language whose code can be manipulated as data at runtime), such as Lisp, Prolog, and Forth.

As to your direct question - the C compiler wouldn't be an interpreter at all. A compiler written in its own language is 'self-hosting', which is a similar property, but more related to bootstrapping. A PHP interpreter in PHP probably wouldn't count, since you would likely be re-implementing a nontrivial amount of the language in the process. The major benefit of a conventional metacircular interpreter is that *doing so isn't necessary* - you can plug in the existing parser, garbage collection (if any), etc., and just write a top-level evaluator with different semantics. In Scheme or Prolog, it's often less than a page of code.

Comment: the reason this is associated with Lisp is that McCarthy (you may have heard of him) gave a description of Lisp evaluation in Lisp.

Comment: While the original Lisp was defined in terms of itself on paper (before it was ever implemented, which is an interesting story in its own right), AotI / SICP have probably done more to directly popularize the idea and (in particular) the term, which is what the question is about.

Also, I have in fact heard of him. Was that really necessary?

Comment: say what you want, the term is associated with Lisp via McCarthy's famous paper. Nice that a Scheme paper and some books pick up the idea 17 years later.

Comment: Alan Kay says: '... that was the big revelation to me when I was in graduate school - when I finally understood that the half page of code on the bottom of page 13 of the Lisp 1.5 manual was Lisp in itself. These were "Maxwell's Equations of Software!" This is the whole world of programming in a few lines that I can put my hand over.'

Answer (score 7):

Here is a definition from the wikipedia page for [metacircular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacircular):

> A meta-circular evaluator is a special
>   case of a self-interpreter in which
>   the existing facilities of the parent
>   interpreter are directly applied to
>   the source code being interpreted,
>   without any need for additional
>   implementation.

So the answer is no in both cases:

- A C compiler is not an interpreter (evaluator).  It translates a program from one form to another without executing it.
- A (hypothetical) PHP interpreter written in PHP would be a self interpreter, but not necessarily metacircular.

Answer (score 4):

To complement the above answers: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?MetaCircularEvaluator

> Lisp written in Lisp implements "eval" by calling "eval". But there is
> no "eval" in many other languages (and if there is, it has different
> semantics), so instead a completely new language system would have to
> be written, one which gives a detailed algorithm for "eval" -- which
> was not necessary in the metacircular case. And that is the magic of
> MetaCircularEvaluators: they reflect an underlying magic of the
> languages in which they are possible.

Answer (score -1):

As i understand it, **a metacircular interpreter is an interpreter that can interpret itself.**

A compiler only translates code, and doesn't execute it.

Any [Turing-complete language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) is mathematically able to emulate any logical computation, so here's an example using [Python](https://www.python.org/). Instead of using CPython to translate this code to CPU instructions and execute it, you could also use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/). The latter is [bootstrapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)), so fulfills some arbitrary criterion that some people use to define a [metacircular interpreter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MetaCircularEvaluator).

```py
"""
Metacircular Python interpreter with macro feature.
By Cees Timmerman, 14aug13.
"""

import re

def meta_python_exec(code):
    # Optional meta feature.
    re_macros = re.compile("^#define (\S+) ([^\r\n]+)", re.MULTILINE)
    macros = re_macros.findall(code)
    code = re_macros.sub("", code)
    for m in macros:
        code = code.replace(m[0], m[1])

    # Run the code.
    exec(code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #code = open("metacircular_overflow.py", "r").read()  # Causes a stack overflow in Python 3.2.3, but simply raises "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" in Python 2.7.3.
    code = "#define 1 2\r\nprint(1 + 1)"
    meta_python_exec(code)
```

> A C compiler written in C is not a MetaCircularEvaluator, because the
> compiler must specify extremely detailed and precise semantics for
> each and every construct. The fact that the compiler is written in the
> target language does not help at **all**; the same algorithms could be
> translated into Pascal or Java or Ada or Cobol, and it would still be
> a perfectly good C compiler.
>
> By contrast, a MetaCircularInterpreter
> for Lisp can't be translated into a non-Lisp language. That's right,
> **cannot** be -- at least, not in any simple one-to one fashion. Lisp
> written in Lisp implements "eval" by calling "eval". But there is no
> "eval" in many other languages (and if there is, it has different
> semantics), so instead a completely new language system would have to
> be written, one which gives a detailed algorithm for "eval" -- which
> was not necessary in the metacircular case.
>
> And **that** is the magic of
> MetaCircularEvaluators: they reflect an underlying magic of the
> languages in which they are possible.

Comment: This is no Meta-circular interpreter. It isn't even an interpreter, it is a prerprocessor. :)

Comment: @Tobias That's a sample meta feature. What about `exec(object[, globals[, locals]])` - [This function supports dynamic execution of Python code.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Comment: `exec` and friends, while being meta-level behavior, do no make a meta-circular interpreter. You can make meta-circular interpreters in languages with no meta-level facilities whatsoever. The thing about _meta-circularity_ is: an interpreter  for Language A _written in_ Lanugage A. Eg, Pascal in Pascal, or Basic in Basic, or Smalltalk in Smalltalk. Using `exec` just passes on to the host Python and does not pose a _new_ implementation of Python. [pypy](http://pypy.org/) is a meta-circular Python, you should look at it!

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for clarifying. PyPy still has an executable and a JIT that feeds machine code to the CPU, so i don't see how that's completely different from `exec`, which is also Python that executes Python.

Comment: It is! Python using `exec` _always_ needs a “host” python. PyPy doesn't, it's standalone. `exec` is a _host_ (ie, Python) facility, and hence you don't have an interpreter at all. Python (the host python) is handling everything for you. In PyPy, everything (method calling, variable access, you name it…) is implemented. **For meta-circularity you need an interpreter written in the language you are interpreting** (or compiler…). The [c2 wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MetaCircularEvaluator) has a nice discussion.

Comment: Machine code doesn't care about its heritage, and Python's `exec` can run Python's `exec` without defining the magic. Even that page itself has circular logic problems, but my code meets both authors' claims.

Comment: meta-circularity is about interpreters (or compilers). Your code is neither, hence not meta-circular. However, it is using _meta-programming_

Comment: @Tobias 'Lisp written in Lisp implements "eval" by calling "eval".' - Your linked definition.

Comment: If you mean the discussion on the C2-Wiki, see at the bottom the Person has the same question. You should look at [the Metacircular Evaluator](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1), where it is nicely discussed: …

Comment: In Lisp/Scheme it is not _Lisp written in Lisp implementing "eval" by calling "eval"_, when the first `eval` is _not the same_ as the second `eval`. The called `eval` is not to be confused with Python's `exec`; the `eval` is _implemented_ by the meta-circular interpreter and not the one of the host language.

Comment: c2 said not having to implement details is the boon of writing a language in itself. Feel free to answer with your own code.

Comment: c2 is more a discussion wiki than an informational one. And yes, “not the details” is one of the merits. But for an interpreter there must be something. You can't say “I made a CPU” and just delegate Assembly to the actual one.

Comment: Yes you can! E.g. [Metascala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Metascala) needs a host to host itself.

Comment: Yes, but they actually have a compiler/interpreter. The equivalent of your implementation would be to just pass-through the guest JVM bytecodes to the host JVM, which would _not_ be metacircular.

Comment: `exec` interprets, compiles, and executes Python; it's inefficient and illogical to duplicate that functionality. PyPy only did it to add functionality. I could call `compile` and mess with the bytecode itself, or parse everything 1:1 first, but that would only obfuscate the claim that **a metacircular interpreter is an interpreter that can interpret itself.**

Comment: I think we should continue our discussion elsewhere :). For example #pypy on Freenode, or wherever you want.

Comment: @Tobias "Using exec just passes on to the host Python and does not pose a new implementation of Python". Neither does Lisp's metacircular evaluator (as described by McCarthy and others). It punts many tasks including parsing, environment capture and garbage collection to the host Lisp implementation.

Comment: While the Lisp metacircular evaluator delegates a lot of aspects to its host Lisp, it indeed does the actual _interpretation_. Using Python's `exec` here does not.

Comment: I think the issue here might be macro expressibility ([comment/links](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/82438)). I may be abusing the term, but I think you could call Python "circularly" macro expressible, bc w/ `exec`/`eval` a Python interpreter can be expressed in Python without global rewrite rules.

IIUC, @Tobias is basically arguing that a metacircular interpreter should only rely on a subset of language features that would _not_ be sufficient to macro express the language.

Comment: I only included the macro bit because that's the only use case i see for self-interpretation.

Comment: This still does not alter the fact that a _program_ is not an interpreter if it passes the execution to something like `exec`. It's a wrapper.

Comment: [It's a mistake to call something a MetaCircularEvaluator just because it's written in itself.](http://wiki.c2.com/?MetaCircularEvaluator)