# How to generate a new PHP file with PHP

Tags: php, dynamically-generated

Can anyone tell me how to Dynamically generate a new php file? Like generate it and then set it's code. Say that there was a user who created an account. When he created that account I would like it to generate his profile page.
Thanks!

Comment: Store the user data in a database of some sort, then you can use a single profile.php file to show all users.

Comment: This is not the way it would typically done. Typically you would store the user's data in a DB, and then populate a HTML template with that data.

Comment: There is a good answer to this question, and it's about 600 pages long: http://lpmj.net/3rdedition/. Or if you're actually looking for code that writes other code, you might look into [LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664618/what-does-it-mean-that-lisp-can-be-written-in-itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), but it's bad practice. It's much easier/better to just have one PHP file, profile.php for example, which takes a GET parameter for the user ID, then dynamically displays the correct information based on the user ID.