# Python meta-circular evaluator

Tags: python, self-interpreter

It's not uncommon for an intro programming class to write a Lisp metacircular evaluator. Has there been any attempt at doing this for Python?

Yes, I know that Lisp's structure and syntax lends itself nicely to a metacircular evaluator, etc etc. Python will most likely be more difficult. I am just curious as to whether such an attempt has been made.

Comment: [PyPy](http://pypy.org/)

Answer (score 8):

For those who don't know what a *meta-circular evaluator* is, it is an interpreter which is written in the language to be interpreted. For example: a Lisp interpreter written in Lisp, or in our case, a Python interpreter written in Python. For more information, [read this chapter from SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html).

As [JBernardo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165177/python-metacircular-evaluator/6165193#6165193), [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is one. However, PyPy's Python interpreter, the meta-circular evaluator that is, is implemented in a statically typed *subset* of Python called [RPython](http://code.google.com/p/rpython/).

You'll be pleased to know that, as of the 1.5 release, PyPy is fully compliant with the official Python 2.7 specification. Even more so: PyPy [nearly always beats Python](http://speed.pypy.org/) in performance benchmarks.

For more information see [PyPy docs](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/index.html) and [PyPy *extra docs*](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/extradoc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think i wrote one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239447/819417):

```
"""
Metacircular Python interpreter with macro feature.
By Cees Timmerman, 14aug13.
"""

import re
re_macros = re.compile("^#define (\S+) ([^\r\n]+)", re.MULTILINE)

def meta_python_exec(code):
    # Optional meta feature.
    macros = re_macros.findall(code)
    code = re_macros.sub("", code)
    for m in macros:
        code = code.replace(m[0], m[1])

    # Run the code.
    exec(code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #code = open("metacircular_overflow.py", "r").read()  # Causes a stack overflow in Python 3.2.3, but simply raises "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" in Python 2.7.3.
    code = "#define 1 2\r\nprint(1 + 1)"
    meta_python_exec(code)
```